# iOS 7 UITableView indexpath row property is nil

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a `UITableView` and it contains a custom `UITableViewCell`. To test, I have an array that has three strings in it. The `UITableView` delegate methods are called as expected, however, the **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath** delegate is always passed an `NSIndexPath` instance whose row property is always `== nil`:

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called 3 times (once for each object in my array). I added the `tableView` from within the designer (storyboard) and created an outlet for it. The UITableViewCell instances appear to be correctly instantiated which each call to this delegate. I just can't wrap my head around why the `[indexPath row]` value is always `nil`.

Interface(s):

In the implmentation file:

```
@interface FirstViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong)AppDelegate *sharedDelegate;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *userList;
@end
```

In the header:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <FacebookDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

Init the custom cell:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView registerClass: [ListCategoryCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListCategoryCell"];
    self.userList = @[@"d", @"g", @"f"]; // make some test data
}
```

And the delegate this is driving me mad:

```
//NSIndexPath.row is nil ?!
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ListCategoryCell";
    ListCategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (ListCategoryCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    cell.titleLabel.text = [self.userList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.detailLabel.text = @"Detail";

    return cell;
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

**Working Now**

I left out some context (and I should not have) that I believe was very relevant to my problem. I created a UIViewController originally and then added a UITableView to this as the view. In the UITableView I created a custom prototype cell. I did all the house work:

`UIViewController` implemented the `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDatasource`.
Created and outlet for the `UITableView`.
Hooked up all the outlets

Everything seemed to work except for the fact that `indextPath.row` property was always `nil`. Some resources I found suggested that custom cells were not visible before the uitableview delegates were called.

In the end I made my class a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Things started working. I am still curious why my original attempt was failing.

Thanks for everyone's time. Some great comments helped me investigate some topics that are "good to know".

Comment: where is userList Property in interface?

Comment: yeah and you just simply need to alloc init your array that might solve your problem

Comment: @murugha23 it's in the implementation file's interface. I'll show that in my post. The values are there however.

Comment: When you say `[indexPath row`] is `nil`, do you mean it is equal to 0 (zero)? I don't think it can be `nil` since it is an `NSInteger`

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper That is correct NSArray array init syntax. http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/13/new-objectivec-literal-syntax/

Comment: @bobnoble No.. it's nil. (lldb) po [indexPath row]
 nil
(lldb)

Comment: Try printing the indexPath, e.g., (lldb) po indexPath;
<NSIndexPath: 0x167e9060> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}. This shows the section is 0 and the row is 0.

Comment: @bobnoble Yes. It does. And on the second iteration path = 0 - 1 Should I not being using [indexPath row] ?? Has something changed?

Comment: From the documentation: "Return - An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range." So my cell must not be visible! Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Based on what you said, it sounds like `indexPath` is OK. What is the problem you are experiencing with the table?

Comment: @bobnoble yes. I think the problem is that the custom UITableViewCell is not registered (shown) before that delegate is called. The documentation says that the indexpath will only contain rows for cells which are visible. I just can't figure out how to make sure the cell is ready and visible before this delegate is called yet.

Comment: What actual problem are you having? Do you not see your data? Did you make the cell in a storyboard? If so, you shouldn't register the class.

Comment: @rdelmar The data is not shown. I did make the cell in the storyboard. The documentation states you should register custom cells. In fact, removing the class registration will cause the application to fail when attempting to dequeue the cell. *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:5251

Comment: How does your - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section look? Also check if if (cell == nil) is ever true, i think it might always be false since you have registered your cell in viewDidLoad.

Comment: If you create the custom cell in the storyboard, DO NOT register it programmatically. Double check the cell identifier...is there a typo in the storyboard, or that it is missing altogether?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite aware of what the documentation says, but it's not correct when dealing with a cell made in the storyboard. You should only register the class when the cell is entirely created in code or when you are using the default table view you get by creating it in code. Try commenting out that line and see what happens.

Comment: @rdelmar I did comment it out and the app crashes with a message that explicitly says to register the class. But.. I believe you are correct if you start with a UITableViewController. I started with a UIViewController and added the UITableview as the view. Then added the cell as a prototype to this. For some reason the registration is necessary in this case. I created a UITableViewController and did not register the cell class.. and your right.. it doesn't complain. That seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide at least two methods in view controller if you want it to manage your table view. They are:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You've already provided the second, so your table view actually can produce cells but it doesn't know how many.The default value the first method returns is nil.That is the reason why you don't even have an index path.

Optionally:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

The default value is one,so you don't need to override this in case you have only one section

Make sure your view controller also follows delegate and datasource protocols.